# How do I call a vb.net property with two parameters?

Tags: c#

The dll I'm calling into is vb.net. It contains the following property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Formatted_BI_SplitLimit(ByVal decLimitPerPerson As Decimal, ByVal decLimitPerOccurrence As Decimal) As String

    Get
        Return Format(decLimitPerPerson, "0000000") + "_" + Format(decLimitPerOccurrence, "0000000")
    End Get

End Property
```

In c#, I get an error whether I use brackets or parenthesis to call it.

```
Formatted_BI_SplitLimit = policy.GHCOPPARateTable.Formatted_BI_SplitLimit[policy.Rating_Liability_Limit_BI_Person, policy.Rating_Liability_Limit_BI_Occurrence];
```

> Error CS1546  Property, indexer, or event
>   'GHCOPPARateTableType.Formatted_BI_SplitLimit[decimal, decimal]' is
>   not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor method

The error tells me what to do, but how do I "directly call the accessor method"?

If I try

```
Formatted_BI_SplitLimit = policy.GHCOPPARateTable.Formatted_BI_SplitLimit(policy.Rating_Liability_Limit_BI_Person, policy.Rating_Liability_Limit_BI_Occurrence);
```

I get another error:

> Error CS1955  Non-invocable member
>   'GHCOPPARateTableType.Formatted_BI_SplitLimit[decimal, decimal]'
>   cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Try `policy.GHCOPPARateTable.get_Formatted_BI_SplitLimit(args);`

Comment: @AlexK., see edit. No joy.

Comment: So you added `get_` ?

Comment: @AlexK., Oh! I missed the `get_`. Please post the answer and win your prize :)